# Magical April Fools prank

Tags: magic

Two days ago, I woke up and I realised that I have these two possibilities:

- Telekinesis (ability to move objects and objects only using my will)
- Invisibility castable on objects only

Both are bound to these rules:

- The objects have to be in my plain sight. Trying to move something what is shown in live TV feed does not do anything. But I can use telescope and my ability will be applied.
- Invisibility is applied just to human eye and normal camera. For example, infrared camera will still see such object
- I have to concentrate in order to make any effect. So object can move as long as I concentrate on it to move. The same applies with invisibility. Even someone calling my name will drop my concentration
- Doing these tricks for more than 4 hours straight provides me headaches. I did see no other side effects on my mind or body
- And as stated above, both abilities apply to objects and objects only. It does not matter how much I concentrate, it simply does *nothing* when cast on people or animals.
- While I can make *any* object invisible (even biggest building in my town), it seems that I can move only "free lying" objects, but then there is no weight limit (tried to move big bulldozer successfully)
- **Edit:** I tried to make Sun invisible for split second. Nothing happened. And I am too afraid to try to move anything *too big* because I do not want to cause any troubles. I want to have fun.
- Also, levitating shoes and then stepping on them is proven to be working. But it requires *a lot* of concentration, so I can do levitating tricks involving people or animals, if they are in some object. But I get headaches in less than hour of doing so.

As I am bit "trickster" by personality:

**I want to make huge April fools joke using these abilities. What should I do?**

I am [Schengen Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) citizen and I am willing to spend up to 4000 Euro if needed (say to travel somewhere).

To put this question in scope of Worldbulding: "Winning criteria" for this is number of people who get "trolled" by my trick.

And, I do not want to commit any crime or do something which cannot be undone. I want to have fun, not to cause troubles

Comment: Is there a limit to the speed which you can move objects? could you move the bulldozer just as quickly as a small pebble? Also, can you levitate yourself?

Comment: I guess `objects only` sort of covers my levitation question, until I wonder if I can levitate my shoes into the air while standing in them.

Comment: I like this question but I think it's a little broad and slightly off-topic, could you try rewriting it?

Comment: Does only affect a single item or can you move contiguous objects (say, turn a beach into a sand castle with your mind)?

Comment: Now that I read the off-topic description, he does state `"Winning criteria" for this is number of people who get "trolled" by my trick`, but I'm not sure anyone can beat turning the Earth, moon, or sun invisible.

Comment: @DoubleDouble Depending on how the telekinesis works, how about capturing (stealing) *another* moon? Like, say, Europa or Rhea?

Comment: @KSmarts I considered something like rearranging stars to spell out a message, but I think the real question is, *does altering the solar system/universe in such a way really count as a "trick"?* I don't think he could anticipate all of the gravitational changes and correct them completely when/if he puts things back.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the Earth, so making it invisible would be a cute trick that would definitely influence a *lot* of people. The moon is also a good option.

Otherwise, I would just walk down the street and randomly invisible people's clothes for short periods of time. Not huge, but highly impactful.

Comment: If you make the sun invisible, does it still light the earth? O.o

Comment: @DoubleDouble: I believe this works by making light not reflect but pass through the object and doesn't affect emitted light. So an invisible bulb will be visible only as the glowing filament.